# How to Prevent a Cell from Changing Location of Referenced Cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want A1 to be consistent with it's value for B1, however when I change B1 location, A1 formula changes accordingly, how can i make A1 fixed?

Please see image below:

[image: Excel Formula]

Comment: The address cannot be moveable and fixed simultaneously. Select one of: it is fixed (=$A$1), fixed by column and moverable by row (=$A1), moveable at all (=A1).

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your question correctly, (which is different from the edit made to the question). I understood that you want A1 always to show the value in B1 even if you move the contents of B1 to another location.

Consider the image below:

[image]

The formula in cell A1 is

```
=indirect("B1")
```

and the formula in A2 is

```
=B1
```

When I drag the text in B1 the outcome is as follows:

[image]

Cell A1 still refers to cell B1 and therefore shows the value '0' (as the cell is now blank) and cell A2 points to the new dragged location B4 where the text was dragged to and therefore shows the original text.

If I enter new text into cell B1, you will notice that A1 still refers to this fixed location and therefore displays the new text.

[image]